# Is Edit and Continue patented?

Tags: edit-and-continue

Just wondering why there isn't that many ide that can edit native code at runtime.

Visual Studio is the only one that can do it?

gdb can ["compile and inject code"](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Compiling-and-Injecting-Code.html#Compiling-and-Injecting-Code), but it only executes a single line of code, doesn't seem like it modifies anything.

Found this https://www.google.com/patents/WO2015200235A1?cl=en , but not sure where can I get the whole patent, it's just ocr without any graphic.

I need to know if that technique of starting all functions with 6 nop is patented, that's all I care. It's pretty old by now. [I plan on developing a language](https://board.flatassembler.net/topic.php?t=20106), if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

To get a full answer you would need to contact a patent attorney, patent search company or engage with an examiner at a particular patent office.

For the patent you found above, you can obtain more complete information, including drawings etc from WIPO PATENTSCOPE [here](https://patentscope.wipo.int/search/en/detail.jsf;jsessionid=B4821FC5166E86A66D512EF0F73F19D8.wapp2nC?docId=WO2015200235&recNum=1&tab=Drawings&maxRec=&office=&prevFilter=&sortOption=&queryString=).

The preliminary search report from WIPO indicates that claims 1,2 7, 9 10 and 15 are insufficiently novel, and claims 1-15 do not constitute an inventive step on the basis of obviousness.

The WIPO Application has entered into national phase under application EP15735802 in Europe, and the website shows two citations, one patent and one NPL (non-patent literature). I can't post the link because I am new to stack overflow and can only post two links, but you can use the 'national phase' tab of the link above to go direct to the European Patent Office website.

You can search [Esp@cenet](https://register.epo.org/advancedSearch?lng=en) using keywords to see if there are other inventions out there which are close to your idea.